# AttributeError: 'SQLiteDialect_pysqlite' object has no attribute '_json_deserializer'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, json-deserialization

So, I've been facing an error since the past week and I am not able to understand as to why the problem is occuring. Is it because of my code or the SQLAlchemy version or something - I am not understanding. This is the error: AttributeError: 'SQLiteDialect_pysqlite' object has no attribute '_json_deserializer'. Can you please suggest me as to what to do for this?
SQLAlchemy version - 1.2.17
sqlite3 version - 3.37.2

Normally this code is not written by me but it s written by some other person. I am trying to fix the bugs. This code is hosted in the server,but the person who wrote the code as able to execute the code and was able to store the forms in the database. So the project is basically related to OCR where we are posting handwritte forms in the db to convert it into text in digital format. And I've tried to uninstall and reinstall the requirements but to no use. This is the code:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from flask import *
from sqlalchemy import *

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///user.db',connect_args={'check_same_thread': False})
engine.connect()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sqlsession = Session()
```

DO I NEED TO CHANGE SOMETHING IN HERE?